# SAPUI5, not OpenUI5, application development in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5

I am working on one pet project to get the better understanding of the SAPIUI5 framework. About me, I am a very experienced front-end developer and enjoy working in VS Code IDE. I started SAPUI5 development in SAP Web IDE and then exported the project to eclipse to run it locally, but in eclipse, I was missing a lot of new features like es6 and es7 and some plugins, so I moved my project to VS Code. In VS code, I introduced grunt to run a small static web server to run my SAPUI5 application, so far it is working fine, and I have no issues, but I am worried about the hidden scenarios that I can't see right now in regards to SAP UI5 deployment and deployment environment. With no experience in the deployment environment and production environment requirements for SAPUI5 client-side application. Can you guys please tell me of any potential issues if there are any in this sort of approach and development of SAPUI5 with VS CODE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Potential issues:**

ES6 and ES7 is not supported across all browsers, so you might want to add Babel to your grunt chain.

**Deployment:**

The grunt plugin [grunt-openui5](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5) lets you minify the code into a single Component-preload.js.

The grunt plugin [grunt-nwabap-ui5uploader](https://github.com/pfefferf/grunt-nwabap-ui5uploader) lets you deploy your code directly to SAP NetWeaver.

---

Here is a sample by SAP which shows their Gruntfile: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-sample-app

Comment: The provided GitHub link should work for SAPUI5 also I guess?. I am planning to use typescript and use grunt to transpile it down to es5. Do you agree with this sort of approach?

Comment: Yes, it should work with SAPUI5. Yes, I agree with this approach :)